# Upgrading to mobx-react@6.0.0 causes an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I've just upgraded from `mobx-react@5.4.4` to version `6.0.0` and my app broke totally. Instead of starting, it consumed more and more memory until it crashed. What I'm looking for is an advice on *how to best approach it...* neither the stack trace nor any of the variables I inspected gave me any hint to any part of my code.

I'm rather sure, I'm doing strange things (I'm rather inexperienced in react/mobx and coming from OO), but that's how I can do now.  I was suspecting some `autorun`s and similar stuff, but removing them changed nothing. I've tried to remove parts of code (until nothing but the bug remains), but this simply takes too long.

The problem is perfectly reproducible (and for now solved by downgrading). With `5.4.4`, everything runs smoothly (good performance, no errors, no warnings, ...).

When upgrading, I ran into a problem with "disposeOnUnmount only supports direct subclasses of React.Component or React.PureComponent", but this was trivial to solve. There may be something similar (a utility which is implemented differently now, and which I'm using in a strange way), but I've tried to remove everything suspicious without a success.

This is the stacktrace:

```
performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20278)
workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20326)
renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:20406)
performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21363)
performWork (react-dom.development.js:21273)
performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21247)
requestWork (react-dom.development.js:21102)
scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20915)
scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:21610)
updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:21636)
updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:21704)
push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:22017)
(anonymous) (react-dom.development.js:22169)
unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21492)
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:22165)
render (react-dom.development.js:22240)
./src/index.tsx (index.tsx:15)
__webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
fn (bootstrap:149)
0 (ReoctoStore.js:62)
__webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap:32)
(anonymous) (main.chunk.js:1)
```

And this is the possibly relevant part of `package.json` (AFAIK everything is at "latest"):

```
    "mobx": "^6.0.0",
    "mobx-decorators": "^5.0.3",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.4",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.14.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-rewire-mobx": "^1.0.9",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.1",
```

Comment: You should start migrating to [mobx-react-lite](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite) for React `^16.8.x`, especially if you are using hooks here and there.

Comment: @jayarjo For sure, I will, but it'll take time - today I added my very first hook. Concerning mobx-react-lite, I'm rather confused as nearly everything is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, the rate at which libraries evolve (or replace each other) these days is ridiculous. I personally used only `observer` wrapper and that part still works.